# A function extension problem

Tags: general-topology

Let $f: A \to Y $ be a continuous function, where $A$ is a closed subset of a space $X$, then is it true that $f$ can always extend to a continuous function $U \to Y$ for some open neighborhood of $A$? Or under what condition this is true? I ask this question because it seems that in the famous paper [Faisceaux Algébriques Cohérents] by Jean-Pierre Serre, he use this kind of conclusion to extend a section of a sheaf.

Comment: A well-known result of this kind is [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem).

Comment: I know the point now, since the projection of the sheaf to the base  space is locally homeomorphism, thus this is a special problem. I think Tietze extension theorem cannot work here since there is no restriction on space here. I believe it's not true in general.

Comment: A [related Question at MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136554/generalizations-of-the-tietze-extension-theorem-and-lusins-theorem) provides a sketch of a case where continuous extension is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

For a toy counterexample, consider the three-point space $X = \{a,b,c\}$, where the open sets are $\emptyset$, $\{b\}$, $\{a,b\}$, $\{b,c\}$, and $X$.  Then $\{a,c\}$ is closed, and can be mapped to the two-point discrete space $\{0,1\}$ by taking $a$ to $0$ and $c$ to $1$.  But this map cannot be extended to $X$ (which is the only open neighborhood of $\{a,c\}$), since $X$ is connected.

This sort of trick can be used for many non-Hausdorff spaces mapping to two points.

As hardmath mentions, the statement applies to maps from normal spaces to the real numbers, by the Tietze extension theorem.

Comment: This and a more subtle (completely regular but not normal) example of Tietze extension theorem not holding were previously described here, [Example where Tietze Extension fails?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143063/example-where-tietze-extension-fails).

Comment: Thank you for the counterexamples and links!