# Given a disconnected subset of $X$, make a continuous function on $X$ that has value 0 and 1 on each component of separation

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $A\cup B$ is a disconnected subset of $X$ where $(A,B)$ is a separation of $A\cup B$.

Does this imply the existence of a continuous function $f : X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(A)=0$ and $f(B)=1$?

If not, what kind of additional conditions are needed?

Comment: If such a function existed, then $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are functionally separated, which is way stronger than being a separation of their union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this is not true. If $A$ and $B$ are closed, then one additionally needs that $X$ is normal, in which case the assertion is a special case of the [Tietze Extension Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem).  In particular, both metric spaces and compact Hausdorff spaces are normal.

You can find some related discussion and counterexamples in answers to this related question:
[Example where Tietze Extension fails?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143063/example-where-tietze-extension-fails)

Comment: Do we need the normality in the whole space $X$, or just the existence of two disjoint open sets that contains each of $A$ and $B$??

Answer (score 2):

Assume such a function exists. By continuity $f$ is zero on $\bar A$ and $f$ is $1$ on $\bar B$. 
This implies $\bar A \cap \bar B = \emptyset$. Therefore, a necessary condition is $\bar A$, $\bar B$ disjoint. This is a stronger condition than $A$, $B$ form a separation of $A\cup B$ which is equivalent to  $\bar A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cap \bar B = \emptyset$.

The condition $\bar A \cap \bar B = \emptyset$ implies the existence of such a function if $X$ is moreover normal ( Urysohn separation theorem).

Also check [Existence of non-constant continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72442)

Comment: So you mean if $\bar{A}\cup\bar{B} = \emptyset$ is given and $X$ may not be normal, then such a function may not exist, right?? What can be a counter-example??

Comment: Of course you mean $\bar A \cap \bar B = \emptyset$. Yeah, there are fairly decent topological spaces such that any real continuous function is constant. Morever, these spaces will have lots of examples of pairs of subsets $A$, $B$ with $\bar A \cap \bar B = \emptyset$. Yes, these spaces can be taken to be regular-- edited the link in the answer above, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A = \{0\}$, $B = \{1\}$ and $X = \{*,0,1\}$ where a basis of open sets is given by $\{*,0\}$ and $\{*,1\}$.